# How to position text below an image, without moving the image?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've attached an image showing what I want. The red circle in the example below represents the image:

[image]

The image (red circle) must be vertically centered in its container. How can I make the text horizontally centered and below the image? If I use a VStack, the VStack will be centered and not the image — the image will move up. I do not know the size of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great use of an overlay combined with an alignment guide.

```
Circle().fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("Title")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { _ in
                    0 // + additiona padding
                }
        }
        //  The last two lines are just the "blue container
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .background(Color.blue)
```

Notice how this is a simple and scaleable solution that doesn't require any fancy code but a single alignment guide.

Comment: This stops working when the circle is smaller than the text. When the circle is smaller than the text, the text gets clipped. I assume the text - as an overlay - cannot be bigger than what it is overlaying, which in this case is the circle. Try making the circle frame smaller (like 20x20) in the code above to see that the text will be changed to ellipsis.

Comment: It seems that a fix for the above problem might be to add `.fixedSize()` modifier last to the Text() element

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset to set the text after circle .The following code may help you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var circleRadius: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .blue], startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)

            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .overlay(GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                        self.circleRadius = geometry.size.width / 2
                    }
                })
            }
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Text")
                    .offset(y: circleRadius + 20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you really trying to achieve here, but if you just want the text to be centred under the image, this should sort out your problem. However, if the text goes multiple lines, the `y` position of the text will move up, unless everything is fixed or the text font scaled down in a single line.

```
    struct CenteredImageView: View {
    let imageSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    let containerSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)
                .position(x: containerSize.width / 2, y: containerSize.height / 2)
            Text("Text")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .position(x: containerSize.width / 2, y: containerSize.height / 2 + (imageSize.height * 0.70))
        }
        .frame(width: containerSize.width, height: containerSize.height)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this UI:

[image]

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var circleRadius: CGFloat = 0
    let circleData = [
        CircleData(color: .red, text: "Text 1233"),
        CircleData(color: .green, text: "Text 22323"),
        CircleData(color: .purple, text: "Text 2323233"),
        CircleData(color: .yellow, text: "Text 4323")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .blue], startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)

            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                ForEach(circleData.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TupleView((
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                            VStack {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(circleData[index].color)
                                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                                    .overlay(GeometryReader { geometry in
                                        Color.clear
                                            .onAppear {
                                                self.circleRadius = geometry.size.width / 2
                                            }
                                    })
                                
                                Text(circleData[index].text)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { _ in circleRadius }
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                        }
                    ))
                    
                    if index < 3 {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.indigo) // You can set the desired color here
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 4)
                            .offset(y: -8) // Offset the rectangles to be below the circles
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
    let text: String
}
```